# no python tabulate in yocto

Tags: python, yocto, openembedded

My python program need

```
    import sys, os, getopt, subprocess, re, socket, tabulate
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

but I searched yocto recipe, it seems no python tabulate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what re you asking, this error simply means you don't have this Python library and the command line utility. you only need to install it as:

```
pip install tabulate
```

Comment: I need to pre-install it.